# Hash algorithm(sha-512) doesn't return fixed length of bits

Tags: python, hash, binary

I am wondering why sha-512 or sha-256 function will return not fixed length bits in hashlib library, Python3.6.x

Firstly, I changed string like 'aaa' or 'mov' with hashlib.sha512 function.

then made return object hexdecimal, then changed hex value into binary.

it happens 2~3 in 100000times.

can anyone explain this?

```
i1 = h.sha512(b'mov')
num= int(i1.hexdigest(),16)
>>>11775820457324453297447618001055999940741095690927818803951219801773598183145805229667200223221871868971369247216868356532234761527576077269523848115505381

binary = bin(num)
>>>'0b1110000011010111000000101110101100011111100100001000101010011111011000010001101101101100010000110000111101010000001011000010011101110110010110111111011000100011011101000001111001111001111000001101101011100111010110001010110101111011001010100001001111010111000111110110110011110001110010111100110100001111011111000101101110001101001011001001111101111110010011010011111110101011010100101101111011001000011001100000000110101110110110001111110101011101001000011111111101110011001000111110000101111111110010001110010101'

len(binary[2:])   # to remove prefix
>>> 514
```

Comment: `len(binary[2:])` is 512, not 514 for this example.  FYI, `int.bit_length()` will also give **minimum** number of bits to represent a number, or just take `len()` of `.hexdigest()` and multiple by 4.

Answer (score 3):

The binary representation of a number doesn't include leading zeros.  Just as `str(1)` and `str(11)` are different lengths because they don't pad with leading zeros to a fixed length.

Comment: That doesn't really explain the OP's `514` answer, however, but it isn't repeatable so is probably a typo.

Comment: When I repeat the example from the question, the length is 512.

Comment: As I said, it's probably a typo :^)  The OP can just do `len(i1.hexdigest()) * 4` for number of bits, since it *does* use leading zeros.  `b'mova'` gives a 511 answer for the reason you state.